# Make list item a link

Tags: html, css

I have a question to ask about list items in html. I have looked for answers but didn't find one working for my problem.

```css
ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 width: 25%;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 display: block;
 font-size: 32px;
 width: 140px;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 color: #282828;
}

.navbardiv {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 height: 50px;
}

a:link,a:visited {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,a:active {
 background-color: #B8B8B8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TestSiteCSS.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbardiv">
<ul>
<li><a href="Page1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Page2.html">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="Page3.html">Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="Page4.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So what my problem is, how do I make the entire list items a link, I have tried for an example making them within a link with a paragraph in them but that didn't work. I want to keep the fonts and size of my links exactly and that's why no answer I found worked. So if you could please answer my question it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? You don't want a gap between your links?

Comment: @Zeta For some reason I can't get the paragraph to look like the link.

Comment: @Zeta Yes I don't want a gap between my links.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (that is, the one with the least amount of changes to your code) I think would be to change the `width` of the `a` tag to `100%`. However you should consider changing your HTML structure to use `nav` tags as suggested in another answer.

```css
ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 width: 25%;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 display: block;
 font-size: 32px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 color: #282828;
}

.navbardiv {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 height: 50px;
}

a:link,a:visited {
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,a:active {
 background-color: #B8B8B8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TestSiteCSS.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbardiv">
<ul>
<li><a href="Page1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Page2.html">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="Page3.html">Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="Page4.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is pretty far from best practices. :(

Comment: True. That's why I wrote that a `nav` tag should be used (as you suggested in your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is below.

Just out of curiosity where did you learn HTML/CSS?

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

nav {
  background: grey;
}

nav a {
  color: initial;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

nav a:hover {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="Page1.html">Home</a>
    <a href="Page2.html">Forum</a>
    <a href="Page3.html">Videos</a>
    <a href="Page4.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm teaching myself at the moment but in a year when I am going to college I am aiming for a programming course. Luckily enough, there is one in my city. I and a few friends of mine usually site at breaks and code. So that's why I am quite bad but everyone has to start somewhere, right?

Comment: It’s awesome that you’re learning. Check out https://dash.generalassemb.ly/ the best site I’ve seen for teaching HTML/CSS to beginners, it’s free you just need to make an account. You will learn a lot and have a much better understanding of these concepts. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add width: 100%; like in your a {} selector

```
a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 100%; /* instead of 140px; */
    background-color: #A0A0A0;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color: #282828;
}
```